# gvisGeoChart Not Recognizing Lat/Long for Marker

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm having issues running some code to plot markers on a US map using `googleVis` and `gvisGeoChart()`. I can run the following example, no problems:

```
require(datasets)
library(googleVis)

GeoMarker <- gvisGeoChart(Andrew, "LatLong", 
                          sizevar='Speed_kt',
                          colorvar="Pressure_mb", 
                          options=list(region="US"))
plot(GeoMarker)
```

Here is the kind of code I'm using. I'm attempting to bring lists of values into a data frame and then use this data to plot markers on a US map.

```
library(googleVis)
library(ggmap)

cities <- c("Norman, OK", "Madison, WI", "Tallahassee, FL")
test <- as.data.frame(cities)
test$rank <- c(2,1,3)
colnames(test) <- c("City","Rank")
geocodes <- geocode(as.character(test$City))
new <- data.frame(test[,1:2],geocodes)

TestPlot <- gvisGeoChart(new, sizevar='Rank',options=list(region="US"))
plot(TestPlot)
```

I then receive the following error:

`Error in data.frame(Latitude = numeric(0), Longitude = numeric(0), Rank = c(2,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3`

I have searched and can't find too many tutorials on using `googleVis` in R and especially with regards to gvisGeoChart apart from the documentation. I've inspected the `Andrew` data frame and used `str()` and can't find anything different between the two data sets.

Thanks for any and all help and please let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

```
new$latlong<-paste(new$lat, new$lon, sep=":")
TestPlot <- gvisGeoChart(new, "latlong", colorvar='Rank',options=list(displayMode="Markers", region="US"))
plot(TestPlot)
```

I think it's just the way your lat/lon were formatted.